# Submenu links padding

Tags: html, css

I have a submenu with 10 links (html+css) and there is a big gap between them (like 5px). Is there any way to make it smaller ,to put link under link imediatly. Submenu structure below.

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
</ul>

.nav ul {
position: absolute;
background-color:#133966;
white-space: nowrap;
border-bottom: 5px solid  orange;
z-index: 10;
margin-top:4px;
left: -99999em;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

.nav a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0px 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 80%;
letter-spacing: 2px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
}
```

[UPDATE] it seems to take .nav a {padding} attribute, but even with padding 0 is still a big space between them.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to find out what is going around each of those links.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to find out exactly what element is creating the margin first, before trying to remove margin and padding from items via CSS. As explained, use the developer tools to get a visual to see what element is creating the margin. I suspect it could be the `a` link within your `<li>`. Could you give a better example of your list of links?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set: margin-bottom:0px !important;